# How did the map crucial to the plot of "The Force Awakens" end up on Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

From Wikipedia's plot summary of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*:

> Poe Dameron, the Resistance’s best pilot, is sent to retrieve a map to Luke's location from a village on the planet Jakku.

How did that map end up in that village on Jakku in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer in *Visual Dictionary* on page 14 for Lor San Tekka.

> A seasoned traveler and **explorer of the more remote fringes of the galaxy**, ... The spiritual San Tekka **has settled** with a colony of villagers in the remote Kelvin Ravine on Jakku *(elsewhere they mention that the whole colony was spiritual)*.

He helped search for Jedi lore:

> In his travels, Lor San Tekka uncovered much of the history of the Jedi Knights that the Galactic Empire had tried so hard to erase.
>   Others now seek him for his knowledge of Jedi secrets.
>
> KEEPER OF FAITH - Though San Tekka is not Force sensitive, he has witnessed its power firsthand.
>   During the dark times of Emperor Palpatine's rule, San Tekko was a follower of the Church of the Force.
>   This underground faith was made up of loosely affiliated worshippers of the Jedi ideals, who steadfastly believed that one day their light would return to the galaxy.

So, the map ended up on Jakku because Lor San Tekka did. And he had the map because of his prior connection to Leia and Luke and Resistance, his past as explorer and Jedi Indiana Jones.

Answer (score 27):

The character who Poe meets seems to know Leia and her family quite well. The last paragraph of the opening crawl reads as:

> Leia has sent her most daring pilot on a secret mission to Jakku, where an old ally has discovered a clue to Luke’s whereabouts....

The name of this character is:

> [Lor San Tekka](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lor_San_Tekka)

And according to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page):

> [Lor San Tekka](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lor_San_Tekka) was an individual who lived on the Western Reaches planet of Jakku approximately 29 years after the Battle of Jakku. San Tekka was a follower of The Church of the Force, an underground faith of loosely affiliated worshipers of the Jedi ideals.

Even more info from the official *Star Wars* site itself:

> A legendary traveler and explorer, [Lor San Tekka](http://www.starwars.com/databank/lor-san-tekka) is a longtime ally of the New Republic and the Resistance. After the Battle of Endor, San Tekka helped Luke Skywalker recover secret Jedi lore that the Empire had tried to erase, and Leia Organa hopes the old scout can now help find her brother. Following decades of adventure, San Tekka retired to live simply on Jakku, where he follows the dictates of the once-forbidden Church of the Force. But his retirement is fated to be anything but peaceful.

As he states to Poe:

> The general. I knew her as royalty

And later on…

> …he also talks to Kylo about his family indicating he knows his lineage

But the map also appears to have been on Jakku for some time.

It is possible that Luke entrusted it to him.

Comment: I can't wait to know more about that character. Probably a former subaltern to Leia.

Comment: +1. I was about to ask about Lor San Tekka and this answered my question. I'm also highly suspicious that he was aware of Rey's abilities, and was keeping a distant eye on her much as Kenobi did for Luke on Tatooine.

Comment: Way to mind an orphaned kid on a strange world, leave her to scavenge for food and live in an abandoned and derelict structure. Someone was looking out for her interests alright.

Answer (score -1):

its unknown at the minute how he got the map and to be honest i think they want it to remain like that simply for the time being, look what they did this year with the movie rogue one. i think they will eventually make a movie based on that featuring in it not as the main objective but i could see them doing a movie on how they got the map to Luke.

Think about it in the force awakens the key objective is a map that has which has basically came out of no where.

a new hope's key objective was the plans to the death star which we later got a movie about IE Rogue One.

they won't do it yet but i could see it sometime after the sequel trilogy has ended.

Answer (score -3):

I think as an adventurer, Lor San Tekka discovered the location of the original Jedi Temple. I also think that he was asked to guard the archives of the temple, much like the knight in The Last Crusade. At some point before the events of ANH, Obi-Wan Kenobi fathered a child on Tatooine. Fearing for the child's safety, he sent the child to the Jedi Island to be looked after by the Church of the Force. Years later, after Luke destroys Vader and the Emperor, Obi-Wan's spirit reveals the location of the Jedi Island to Luke. When Luke arrives, he learns of the death of Kenobi's child, but also discovers an infant, born on the island. Luke takes the infant as his own, and recovers information from the temple archives to aide him in his new work of restoring the Jedi Order. After Ren turns (and spares Rey), Luke returns the child to Lor San Tekka and tells him to take the child far away ("so afraid to leave"). He uploads a map to the island into R2-D2, except one fragment which he entrusts to Lor San Tekka.  Not only does it explain why LST has the map fragment, but it also explains how Ren knows Rey, why Rey is so important, and why Rey sees visions of an ocean and an island.  Luke leaves just enough breadcrumbs (and a getaway vessel) so that when Rey is ready, she will find her way home.  It also explains why R2 wakes up as soon as Rey is nearby.  He's waiting for her.

Comment: That's an interesting piece of fan-fiction. Too bad there's nothing to corroborate any of it.

Comment: Others, although not Abrams, have suggested the same reason for R2D2's [awakening](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45054/what-prompted-r2-d2-to-wake-up). I could not see any reason for it when I watched the film. It felt a little contrived.

Comment: How would Obi-Wan father a child 15 years after his death?

Comment: @MiloPrice Maybe in Force Heaven, he learned how from whomever impregnated Anakin's mother?