# What sources tell us about the Battle of Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110945/3823) points out that 
 according to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page):

> [Lor San Tekka](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lor_San_Tekka) was an individual who lived on the Western Reaches planet of Jakku approximately 29 years after the Battle of Jakku. San Tekka was a follower of The Church of the Force, an underground faith of loosely affiliated worshipers of the Jedi ideals.

And presumably the crashed Imperial Star Destroyer that Rey spelunks at the beginning of *The Force Awakens* crashed during that battle.

But Wookieepedia is not a reference without backup links.   What's the origin of this statement and what other types of information are out there?

## What canonical sources tell us about the Battle of Jakku ?

Comment: Loads. More than can sensibly fit into this answer; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Jakku

Comment: Regarding the crashed Star Destroyer - read all about it in the canon book "Lost Stars" where you can find out what leads up to it crashing and the crash itself

Comment: @Richard: Some of the stuff in that article is hard to believe. Like the Rebellion just leaving any and all survivors on the planet to fend from themselves after the Empire retreated.

Comment: OK, folks, I'm editing this to make it less broad to focus on what the sources are.   It should satisfy those who voted too broad.

Comment: Appearances
Lost Stars (First appearance)
Hyperspace Mountain
Star Wars Battlefront
Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens (Wreckage only)
Sources
SWInsider "Launch Pad"—Star Wars Insider 158 (First mentioned)
SWCustom-2011 EA Previews the Battle of Jakku on Star Wars Battlefront! on StarWars.com (backup link on Archive.org)
SWCustom-2011 Star Wars Battlefront: Battle of Jakku Teaser Trailer on StarWars.com (backup link on Archive.org)
Star Wars: The Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections
Star Wars: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary
Star Wars: Rey's Survival Guide

Comment: I think this is a useful question.  I bet many people had this very question after seeing *The Force Awakens*. +1

Comment: @Praxis, it was more useful before I was forced to neuter it due to the Too Broad voters :(

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the crashed Star Destroyer and some of the space battle - read all about it in the Disney canon book ***"Lost Stars"***

Comment: why a downvote - it's the only actual answer to the question so far, and it has the added bonus of being accurate. The question didn't ask for details as to the events, just *what sources* detailed the events.

Comment: I agree: you've answered the question *as asked*.  +1