# Was the Church of the Force on Jakku watching over Rey

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey

Not sure there is any evidence for this. Pure speculation. Just thought it was an interesting point that these people are on the same planet and within "BB-8 rolling distance" of Rey.

We all know there are no coincidences because the Force determines fate, as evidenced by prophecies fulfilled and defeating unlikely odds on a regular basis. I feel it would be clumsy for the films not to at least suggest a link, if not confirm it. I wouldn't have a hissy fit, but it would be implausible to think they would be ideal caretakers for an abandoned/hidden force sensitive child and never come across her, while so close in a galaxy so vast.

Comment: You might want to link to an article about the [Church of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Church_of_the_Force), people may not know what you're talking about since it wasn't actually mentioned in the movie itself.

Comment: Unclear. But "Rey's Survival Guide" apparently contains a reference to [Dasha Promenti](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dasha_Promenti), someone revealed to be a member of said church. That might also explain how Rey knew about the legends of the Jedi order. Perhaps someone with that book could find the reference and let us know.

Comment: Not sure why the DV's maybe remove the part about speculation and add a little info on the church. This question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110914/how-did-the-map-crucial-to-the-plot-of-the-force-awakens-end-up-on-jakku?rq=1 references the church as well...